# How do I get a mouse listener on a DefaultMutableTreeNode?

Tags: java, jtree, mouselistener

I know I can add a mouseListener to a Jtree, but I need to double click on one of his elements and doSomething();

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation of JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html):

> If you are interested in detecting either double-click events or when
>   a user clicks on a node, regardless of whether or not it was selected,
>   we recommend you do the following:

```
final JTree tree = ...;

 MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         int selRow = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
         TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
         if(selRow != -1) {
             if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                 mySingleClick(selRow, selPath);
             }
             else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                 myDoubleClick(selRow, selPath);
             }
         }
     }
 };
 tree.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: I still don't know why I need selRow and selPath.I need the double clicked node's name.Seems like if I get the source, the object is a Jtree. I can't cast it as a node.(I get class cast exception)

Comment: @AdrianStamin The node you clicked on is the last component of `selPath` that you get with [selPath.getLastPathComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getLastPathComponent())

Comment: Thanks, it works!I didn't get what that path is for.Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Check this:-

```
  public class NetworkTree extends JPanel implements TreeSelectionListener {
  private JTree tree;
  private static int PANEL_WIDTH=250;
  private static int PANEL_HEIGHT=500;
private static String lineStyle = "Horizontal";

public NetworkTree() {
DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Site(
                1,1,"Network","",3));
getSubNodes(top,0);
tree = new JTree(top);
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);
add(treeView);

tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    newNodeSelected();
  }
});
 }
.....
    public void newNodeSelected() {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello");
}
```

.....
    }